# How can I filter the entire spreadsheet in Excel VBA instead of the specific rows the macro discovered?

Tags: excel, vba

Here's a minimal example. I would like to show only rows for which a particular element is empty. Here's what the Excel Macro generator gives me.

```
Sub ShowEmpties()
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$M$4922").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="="
End Sub
```

Instead of A1-M4922, which is specific to this particular sheet, how can I have it filter the entire sheet no matter how many rows there are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UsedRange` revers to the range of your worksheet which contains data:

```
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="="
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="="
```